# WebCenter Sites 11gr1 installation: unable to proceed with fwadmin login

Tags: webcenter-sites

I am facing relate problem. I have installed WebCenter Sites on Weblogic. My environment is

RHL 5
Oracle 11gr1

During deploying "cs" on our managed server I got log4j error. I have to edit weblogic.xml and added following

```
<container-descriptor>
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

The same log4j error occurred while deploying "cas" and had to add the above to cas weblogic.xml

Then there is error for cas.properties file not found.

The file is located 
/home/oracle/oracle/webcenter/sites/bin
with three other files

host.properties
jbossTicketCacheReplicationConfig.xml
and
libsigar-amd64-linux.so

Once I copied them in /cas/WEB-INF/classes I was able to deploy cas with no errors and Webcenter Sites installation went successful.

I can successfully access login page

[http://192.168.14.125:16400/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.14.125%3A16400%2Fcs%2Fwem%2Ffatwire%2Fwem%2FWelcome]

as soon as i try to login with fwadmin, it went into redirect loop.

Application server messages

```
INFO: Reloading registered services.
Oct 9, 2012 2:36:22 PM org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl load
INFO: Loaded 0 services.

Oct 9, 2012 2:38:43 PM org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl grantServiceTicket
INFO: Granted service ticket [ST-11-ItqcwCaffbrXydPeBtMB-cas-192.168.14.125-1] for service [http://192.168.14.125:16400/cs/wem/fatwire/wem/Welcome] for user [fwadmin]
I have following in my sites.log file

2012-10-09 14:38:43,414] [ERROR] [.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [sso.cas.filter.CASFilter] Ticket ST-10-EpWYIR3xPPgVLtk2HmZf-cas-192.168.14.125-1 is already validated or CAS is not avalilable. Request [http://192.168.14.125:16400/cs/wem/fatwire/wem/Welcome] from 192.168.14.144
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create XMLReader
at org.jasig.cas.client.util.XmlUtils.getXmlReader(XmlUtils.java:44)
at org.jasig.cas.client.util.XmlUtils.getTextForElement(XmlUtils.java:116)
at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator.parseResponseFromServer(Cas20ServiceTicketValidator.java:69)
at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:188)
at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.CASProvider.validate(CASProvider.java:306)
at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:425)
at com.fatwire.wem.sso.SSOFilter.doFilter(SSOFilter.java:51)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(Unknown Source)
at org.jasig.cas.client.util.XmlUtils.getXmlReader(XmlUtils.java:42)
... 16 more
```

I edited setDomainEvn.sh with the entries mentioned in this post

```
if [ "${PRE_CLASSPATH}" != "" ] ; then
PRE_CLASSPATH="/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar;/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/quartz-1.5.2.jar;/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-api-1.2.jar;/home/oracle/oracle/webcenter/sites/MSXML.jar${COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME}/modules/oracle.jdbc_11.1.1/ojdbc6dms.jar${CLASSPATHSEP}${PRE_CLASSPATH}"
export PRE_CLASSPATH
else
PRE_CLASSPATH="/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar;/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/quartz-1.5.2.jar;/export/home/bea/domains/cas/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-api-1.2.jar;/home/oracle/oracle/webcenter/sites/MSXML.jar${COMMON_COMPONENTS_HOME}/modules/oracle.jdbc_11.1.1/ojdbc6dms.jar"
export PRE_CLASSPATH
fi
```

Even after that I got same errors.

It is interesting to observer that I have installed Webcenter Sites with oracle database option but in my cas.properties file I have following entry

```
#database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
database.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

Any Ideas what is going on here?

BR
AAN

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29495_01/doc.1111/webcenter_sites_11gr1_install_on_weblogic.pdf while installing WCS? It does sound like the installation didn't go exactly how it's supposed to go.